# ER Diagram 1:N relationship Convert

Tags: erd

If I have Employees and project and relationship one-to-many (many for projects i.e Employees can be assigned to multiple projects and one project is assigned to exactly one employee)
the table will be:

Employees (empid,name,phone)

Projects(proid,proname,cost,**empid**)

can I move proid key to employees table as :

Employees(empid,name,phone,**proid**)

Projects(proid,proname,cost)

This convert will be wrong or still right?
and if the last convert is wrong, why it's wrong?

Comment: Employees can be assigned to multiple projects and one project is assigned to exactly one employee?

Comment: yes Employees can be assigned to multiple projects and one project is assigned to exactly one employee

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `empid` to the `Projects` table. When you would add the `proid` column to the `Employees` table you could only reference one project. If you have an employee assigned to multiple projects you would get something like this:

```
Employees(1, "John", "123-456-789", 42)
Employees(1, "John", "123-456-789", 20)
```

As you see you would have the employee twice in your table, not to mention getting primary key violations. So you have to save the employee id in the `Projects` table.

```
Projects(42, "Research", 10000, 1);
Projects(20, "Analysis", 3000, 1);
```